Configuring Aruba HPE AP22 in Local Management Interface
I'm working with an Aruba HPE AP22, Software version 2.5.0.0_83058. My network consists of seven access points, with one designated to function as the controller.
Upon beginning the configuration, I noticed that it defaults to the Aruba Instant On portal (cloud solution). However, I prefer to configure the AP using the Aruba local management interface.
My questions are:
Is it possible to configure the Aruba AP22 in the local management interface?
If not: do I need to implement a hardware controller to enable local configuration?

Sorry I fail to see based on the info here what this has to do with Ubuntu.

well the Aruba Website redirect me to here when i asked for the Aruba Community . so i asked the question .

As written, I too see no Ubuntu related question, no Ubuntu product/release details and problem for us to help solve on Ubuntu for you.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic
